# Converting from foreach to for

Tags: c#

Tried converting already, still getting errors.. Thank you so much for even watching, but hopefully someone can help. Also it would help me fixing other methods

```
static void PrintHighestHallmark(JeweleryContainer shops)
{
    foreach(JeweleryContainer s in shops)
    {
        int count = s.earring.Count + s.necklace.Count + s.ring.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Parduotuveje " + s.Name + " yra " + count + " auksciausios prabos gaminiai(iu).");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with class JeweleryContainer.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with the rewrite? If you need a sequential counter, you can always introduce one separately.

Comment: You should start changing the for loop to something like `for(int i=0;i<shops.Count;i++)` and then you change all the s in your code to `shops[i]`. Should be easy enough for you to give it a try.

Comment: This is at the lowest level of programming, i think you should start with some research and reading first as any answer will likely not help

Comment: If you don't know how to use arrays and write a for loop, you shouldn't be trying to convert code. Especially when there's no obvious reason to do so.

Comment: "still getting errors" What errors do you get? Please be more specific on what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve and why do you think `for` would solve it? If you want to get totals per shop, there are easy ways to do it that don't involve looping.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you think of using linq? This would also involve looping, just hiding that from the user.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm thingking the OP should read about C# first and that looping isn't the problem here. That's why I didn't post the one-liner. If `for` is an issue, *any* answer will only create more problems. Did the OP create `JeweleryContainer` without implementing `IEnumerable<T>` perhaps? Or implemented `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` and now can't get the properties? Why create `JeweleryContainer` instead of using a `List<JeweleryShop>` ?

Comment: @HimBromBeere if that code compiles, `JeweleryContainer` would have to be a recursive type. That's the only way `foreach(JeweleryContainer s in shops)` could work

Comment: [for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) and [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) and [C# programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/) and [getting started with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/index) and [learning C#](https://www.learncs.org/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Making this question even more unclear without knowing what `JewelryContainer` is.

Comment: This does not make sense as you have posted it.  `JeweleryContainer shops` given the `foreach` implies some sort of collection of "shops" but perhaps that is just the names you use. Better perhaps to tell us the real need and goal here and then show us the classes involved by including that code here in your question.

Comment: The only thing we know about `JeweleryContainer` is that it implements `IEnumerable`. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Note, the `foreach(JeweleryContainer s in shops)` will only have one `JeweleryContainer` as a singular is passed to the method.  Perhaps you meant to pass a collection such as an array or a list for example `PrintHighestHallmark(List<JeweleryContainer> containers)`?

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code and only that as that is all we can see, this may work however, as I stated, not knowing what a `JeweleryContainer` looks like hinders our ability to better answer as stated given your REAL goal is slightly unclear to us.

```
static void PrintHighestHallmark(JeweleryContainer shops)
{
    int count = shops.earring.Count + shops.necklace.Count + shops.ring.Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Parduotuveje " + shops.Name + " yra " + count + " auksciausios prabos gaminiai(iu).");
}
```

Now if the goal is to create an iterator of collection of some sort, start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators

Use a list of containers?

```
static void PrintHighestHallmark(List<JeweleryContainer> shops)
{
    foreach(JeweleryContainer s in shops)
    {
        int count = s.earring.Count + s.necklace.Count + s.ring.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Parduotuveje " + s.Name + " yra " + count + " auksciausios prabos gaminiai(iu).");
    }
}
```

Using a for loop:

```
static void PrintHighestHallmark(List<JeweleryContainer> shops)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < shops.Count; i++) {
        int count = shops[i].earring.Count + shops[i].necklace.Count + shops[i].ring.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Parduotuveje " + shops[i].Name + " yra " + count + " auksciausios prabos gaminiai(iu).");
    }
}
```